# Displaying returned list from a function which loops through a viewModel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've got a function that takes a container and loops through its objects to perform a search and retrieve an array of the found items.

The ViewModel has a container passed like such e.g.:

```
    function ShowRoomBuildingsViewModel() {
            this.LoadModel = function (container) {
    
            for (var u in container.Payload.ShowRoom) {
                if (container.Payload.ShowRoom[u].Inventory!== undefined)
                    this.Content.push(container.Payload.ShowRoom[u].HVehicle, container.Payload.ShowRoom[u].Cars);
    }

    // Definitions
    this.Inventory= ko.observableDictionary();
    this.Content= ko.observableArray();
```

I'm trying to create an ObservableArray object to loop through in my front end using `<!-- ko foreach -->`. The below code should retrieve either one result or multiple.

```
this.Content = function (container) {
    var concatedList;               
    Content.forEach(element, elementIndex => {
        var Content1 = container.Payload.Inventory.HVehicle.find(el => el.ID == element.ID);
        if (Content1 != undefined) {
            concatedList[elementIndex] = element;
            concatedList[elementIndex].push(Content1);
        }                    
    });
    return concatedList;
};
```

I've tried putting breakpoints to see what is happening inside, but it doesn't go in. I'm not sure if this is the correct approach or if it even works, but it is not showing any errors. In the first loop, where it populates `Content`, I can see that there are five results.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.